# Dividing string and converting to Int

Tags: c, string, int

I got a problem. In my program I want to divide string, save each of substrings in variables and then convert them to int so i can make some calculations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>



int main()
{

 char *token;
 char *token2;
char line[] = "-500,600";
char *search = ",";


printf("%s\n",line);


token = strtok(line, search);
printf("token1: %s\n",token);


token2 = strtok(NULL, search);
printf("token2: %s\n",token2);  


 int n = toInt(token);
 int m = toInt(token2);

  printf("String  = %s\nInteger = %d\n", token, n);
   printf("String  = %s\nInteger = %d\n", token2, m);

  int b = n*3;
  int c = m*2;

    printf("%d\n",b);
    printf("%d",c);



  return 0;
}

int toInt(char a[]) {
  int c, sign, offset, n;

  if (a[0] == '-') {  // Handle negative integers
    sign = -1;
  }

  if (sign == -1) {  // Set starting position to convert
    offset = 1;
  }
  else {
    offset = 0;
  }

  n = 0;

  for (c = offset; a[c] != '\0'; c++) {
    n = n * 10 + a[c] - '0';
  }

  if (sign == -1) {
    n = -n;
  }

  return n;
}
```

It works fine when input values are for example:

```
char line[] = "500,600";
char line[] = "-500,-600";
char line[] = "500,-600";
```

But when i try

```
char line[] = "-500,600";
```

i got strange output:

[image]

There might be something wrong with toInt function but I can't say what is wrong. Maybe someone of you have an idea.

I know that i can make that simpler using atoi function but I'm interested what is wrong here.

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: `sign` need initialized like `int sign = 0;` Also Put prototype `int toInt(char a[]);` before using it.

Comment: Right, if `a[0] != '-'`, then the next check to `sign` will read from an uninitialized variable, which is undefined behavior

Comment: `sign` can be also set to 1 which defaults number to a positive number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for quick answers in comments. Initializing `sign` solving my problem.